# find out most frequent value in dictionary and assign to key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary with strings as keys, and also strings as values. First, 
I want to find the most frequent val in my dictionary. Second, I want to assign most frequent value to key

```
input_dict = {
    'A': [1963], 'B': [1963,1964] 
    'C': [1966], 'D': [1964,1965] 'E': [1965,1967]
    'F': [1968,1969] 'G': [1969], 'H': [1971,1966]
    'I': [1967], 'J': [1967], 'K': [1968,1969]
    'L': [1969] ,'M': [1969],
    'N': [1970,1971]}
```

now if we calculate most frequent val in this dict are:

```
year    No. of times occurrence

1969    5 times
1967    3 times
1963    2 times
1964    2 times
1965    2 times
1966    2 times
1968    2 times
1971    2 times
1970    1 times
```

i would like assign only one most frequent val to key if that value exists in that key.if no.of occurrence same then it should be any one of them

expected output:

```
{'A': [1963], 'B': [1963], 'C': [1966], 'D': [1964], 'E': [1967],'F': [1969] 'G': [1969], 'H': [1971],'I': [1967], 'J': [1967], 'K': [1969],'L':[1969],'M': [1969],'N': [1971]}
```

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: in this ex. most frequent year is 1969 so i wants to assign this value to key then 1967,if the val presents in that key

Comment: For B, why is 1963 chosen over 1964? They each have two occurrences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this. I'm not exactly sure how you want to assign your keys since some have the save amount of occurrences so ill leave that part up to you.

[Online Compiler Version](https://onlinegdb.com/B1xn9jqkr)

```
input_dict = {
    'A': [1963], 'B': [1963,1964], 
    'C': [1966], 'D': [1964,1965], 'E': [1965,1967],
    'F': [1968,1969], 'G': [1969], 'H': [1971,1966],
    'I': [1967], 'J': [1967], 'K': [1968,1969],
    'L': [1969] ,'M': [1969],
    'N': [1970,1971]}


popularity_dict = {}
for key in input_dict:
    items = input_dict[key]
    for item in items:
        try:
            popularity_dict[str(item)] = popularity_dict[str(item)] + 1
        except:
            popularity_dict[str(item)] = 1
print(popularity_dict)

#Go through each key and resassing value if needed
for key in input_dict:
    if len(input_dict[key]) > 1:
        print('Bad finding most recent year')
        mostPopYear = 0
        for year in input_dict[key]:
            print(year)
            pop = popularity_dict[str(year)]
            if pop > mostPopYear:
                mostPopYear = pop
                mostPop = year

        input_dict[key] = [mostPop]

print(input_dict)
```

Comment: Its not the best solution but check the updated online compiler version

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for,I appreciate your critical thinking.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use collections module

```
input_dict = {
    'A': [1963], 'B': [1963,1964] ,
    'C': [1966], 'D': [1964,1965] , 'E': [1965,1967],
    'F': [1968,1969] , 'G': [1969], 'H': [1971,1966],
    'I': [1967], 'J': [1967], 'K': [1968,1969],
    'L': [1969] ,'M': [1969],
    'N': [1970,1971]}
l = []
for x in input_dict.values():
    for y in x: #because your values are lists
        l.append(y)
import collections
counter = collections.Counter(l)
#counter calculates the frequencies for you
m = []
for x,y  in dict(counter).items():
    m.append(counter.most_common(1)[0][0])
    del counter[counter.most_common(1)[0][0]]
```

m is your frequency list
now for eack key check if value of m[0] exists if not m[1] and so on

let me know if you face problem in the comments